# React.js client route match giving "Invalid prop `routes` supplied to `Router`."

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

Compiling my packages with webpack (there is a separate vendor.js and then an app.js, vendor.js just requires some basics like react, etc). I'm wondering why when I use {...renderProps} format in the Router declaration, that it throws this error. If I change {...renderProps} to the standard routes={routes} format, it seems to work, but everyone tends to use {...renderProps}, and I'm trying to figure out why it isn't working for me. I believe the dot alias {...x} is a stage-0 feature, so I have stage-0 defined in my webpack presets, but doesn't seem to affect the outcome. Here's my files:

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { match, Router, RouterContext, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createHistory } from 'history'
import routes from './components/routes/AppRoute.jsx';

const { pathname, search, hash } = window.location;
const location = pathname;

match({ routes, location }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
   render(
        <Router 
            {...renderProps} 
            history={browserHistory} 
        />, 
        document.getElementById('react-app')
    );
})
```

/components/routes/AppRoute.jsx is:

```
import AppShell from '../AppShell.jsx';
import Index from '../Index.jsx';

if(typeof require.ensure !== "function") require.ensure = function(d, c) { c(require) }

module.exports = {
  path: '/',
  component: AppShell,
  indexRoute: Index,
  childRoutes: [
    { path: 'test', 
        getComponent(location, cb) {
            require.ensure([], (require) => {
              cb(null, require('../Test.jsx'))
            })
          }
    },
    { path: 'user', 
        getComponent(location, cb) {
            require.ensure([], (require) => {
              cb(null, require('../User.jsx'))
            })
          }
    },
    { path: '*', 
        getComponent(location, cb) {
            require.ensure([], (require) => {
              cb(null, require('../NotFound.jsx'))
            })
          }
    },
    { path: 'app-shell', component: AppShell }
  ] 
}
```

This seems to be exported correctly and being imported correctly into app.js, as console.log shows the object as expected.

But for some reason upon page load, the browser gives:

```
dll.vendor.js:330 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `routes` supplied to `Router`.
    in Router
```

This error is being displayed from the dll.vendor.js file (not app.js), but I'm not sure that matters as I react is loaded into the vendors file, and react is responsible for showing the errors.

Anyone have an idea as to why?

Answer (score 1):

Does changing the `match` in `app.js` from `<Router>` to `<RouterContext>` and deleting the history prop fix it?

```
match({ routes, location }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
   render(
        <RouterContext 
            {...renderProps} 
        />, 
        document.getElementById('react-app')
    );
})
```

That's what is recommended in [react-router's docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md)

Comment: Yeah, worked. I dunno, I had the regular <Router /> working before, but I changed a lot of webpack stuff and for some reason it is complaining now. However, switching to RouterContext worked. Thanks man!

Comment: Ah, just noticed a bug... looks like if I use <RouterContext>, none of my linking works! Any <Link to="/..." /> components don't go anywhere, the url doesn't change, no errors. If I change it to <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} /> then everything works fine... weird

Comment: Ah, see @uni_nake's answer. You're using the server side rendering solution, I didn't notice you're only trying to route client side.

Answer (score 0):

### React router 2

It is because the `Router` component does not take `routes` as a prop.

As this is for server-side rendering, the code need to use `RouterContext` rather than `Router`.

### React router 4

`match` and `Router` has been removed to make life simpler and been replaced with `MemoryRouter`, `BrowserRouter` and `ServerRouter`.

```
/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { ServerRouter/* , createServerRenderContext */ } from 'react-router';
// todo : remove line when this PR is live
// https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3820
import createServerRenderContext from 'react-router/createServerRenderContext';
import { makeRoutes } from '../../app/routes';

const createMarkup = (req, context) => renderToString(
  <ServerRouter location={req.url} context={context} >
    {makeRoutes()}
  </ServerRouter>
);

const setRouterContext = (req, res, next) => {
  const context = createServerRenderContext();
  const markup = createMarkup(req, context);
  const result = context.getResult();
  if (result.redirect) {
    res.redirect(301, result.redirect.pathname + result.redirect.search);
  } else {
    res.status(result.missed ? 404 : 200);
    res.routerContext = (result.missed) ? createMarkup(req, context) : markup;
    next();
  }
};

export default setRouterContext;
```

for a working demo take a look at [react-lego](https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego/blob/react-router-4)

Comment: This isn't for server-side rendering. I had that working, but so many complications between getting the server to render and restart in a timely manner with webpack, I just wanted to simplify it for now. Thanks though.

Comment: ah, ok - the confusion was around the use of `reactRouter.match` which i believe is for server-side rendering only.

Comment: Really? I've read using match() on the client side helps with some bugginess in some cases...

Comment: well, i see according to this its ok : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md#async-routes

but i've not had the need for it as data is based on components and not routes. i.e. you can have a component that needs async data.  This would mean never having async routes.

Answer (score 0):

ah, ok - the confusion was around the use of `reactRouter.match` and `RouterContext` both of which I believe are for server-side rendering only.

You should have a `Router`, which takes children and a history (browser or memory).

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history} >
        <Route path="/" component={ MainLayout }>
          <IndexRoute { ...indexRoute(routes.homepage) } />
          <Route { ...routes.game } />
          <Route { ...routes.notFound } />
        </Route>
    </Router>,
document.getElementById('html'));
```

Comment: But my routes are defined externally, so I have to use routes={routes}, but my original question is trying to determine how to use {...renderProps}. I guess the client just has to use Router with routes and history defined as separate properties?